# remove all occurences of dot only between two strings and not in the rest of the file

Tags: bash, sed

apologies if this has been asked before - I could not find an answer to my question though

assuming there is the following file

```
touch test2

echo "refH.fasta = ref/GCA_013924565.1_ASM1392456v1_genomic.fasta" >> test2


echo "subjectGCA_017717955.1_PDT000990484.1_genomic_querry.fasta = GCA_017717955.1_PDT000990484.1_genomic.fasta" >> test2

echo "file=subjectGCA_017717955.1_PDT000990484.1_genomic_querry" >> test2
```

in the above file I would like to remove the dots ONLY between the strings 'subject' and '_querry' but not in the rest of the file.

Therefore the output should look like this:

```
refH.fasta = ref/GCA_013924565.1_ASM1392456v1_genomic.fasta
subjectGCA_0177179551_PDT0009904841_genomic_querry.fasta = GCA_017717955.1_PDT000990484.1_genomic.fasta
file=subjectGCA_0177179551_PDT0009904841_genomic_querry
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -lpe '$_=$_.split(/(subject.*?_query)/).
    map{|s| s=s[/subject.*?_query/] ? s.gsub(/\./,"") : s}.join' test2
```

Or Perl:

```
perl -lnE '@a=(); for $x (split /(subject.*?_query)/){ 
    $x=~s/\.//g if $x=~/subject.*?_query/; 
    push @a,$x } 
    say join("",@a)' test2
```

It is *possible* entirely in Bash:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
    if [[ $line =~ (subject.*_query) ]]; then 
        line=${line/""${BASH_REMATCH[1]}""/""${BASH_REMATCH[1]//./}""}
    fi     
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done <test2
```

But this only handles one match per line.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
sed '
   /.*\(subject.*_query\).*/{
      # hold pattern space
      h
      # filter only the interesting part
      s//\2/
      # remove the dots
      s/\.//g
      # grab hold space
      G
      # reshuffle for output
      s/\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)subject.*_query\(.*\)/\1\2\3/
   }
'
```